# Replacing a string using regular expressions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using CKEditor to edit and save HTML content.

There is a scenario whereby there can sometimes be a lot of

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

which build up.

I am trying to write some Javascript which would lidentify if there are more than 2  `<p>&nbsp;</p>` in the string and if so, replace them all with 2.  So if there are 3, replace with 2.  if there are 4, then replace with 2 and so on ..

That way there will only ever be up to 2 and no more.

I don't know where to begin with this and have been scouring the web for ideas, but nothing.  Any suggestions on some libraries that might exist, or does anyone have some simple suggestions or examples on how I may be able to tackle using javascripts Regular expressions and string replacement to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var text = "<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>something else<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>something else<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>";
text.replace(/(<p>&nbsp;<\/p>\s*){3,}/g, '<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>');
```

Comment: This won't work when multiple line-breaks are between the paragraphs. selecting mutliple whitespaces with `\s+?` seems to fix that

Comment: You are right ThomasAltmann. Fixed.

Comment: I had no idea you could use regexp to limit the number of replaces like that, I used an if statement and your solution is really neat! gratz!

Answer (score 0):

First I must say that you need to read this: 
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
TLDR: Next time share what you have tried so far.

Second I've made this code that's pretty readable and shows the basic on how to solve this kind of replacement.

```js
const $ = (selector, startNode = document) => [...startNode.querySelectorAll(selector)];
const nbsp = '<p>&nbsp;</p>';
const greg = new RegExp(nbsp, 'g');
const count = function (s) {
  return (s.match(greg)||[]).length;
};
const cleanContent = function (contentTag) {
  var str = contentTag.innerHTML;
  var occurr = count(str);
  while (occurr > 2) {
    str = str.replace(new RegExp(nbsp), '');
    occurr = count(str);
  }
  contentTag.innerHTML = str;
};

$('.content').forEach(cleanContent);
```

```css
.content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  counter-reset: p;
}
.content p {
  margin: 0;
}
.content p:before {
  counter-increment: p;
  content: "p: " counter(p);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```